# CSS animation swing effect

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

I found this really interesting css animation effect. However, my knowledge is not enough to find where might be the problem. If someone can help me I will be really grateful. Thanks in advance.

PS: My idea is really simple, when you hover the div to start swinging.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes swing {
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 15deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 15deg);
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -10deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -10deg);
  }

  60% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 5deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 5deg);
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -5deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -5deg);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes swing {
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 15deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 15deg);
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -10deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -10deg);
  }

  60% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 5deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 5deg);
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -5deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -5deg);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);
  }
}

.swing {
  position:relative;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
}

.swing:hover{
  -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
  transform-origin: top center;
  -webkit-animation-name: swing;
  animation-name: swing;
}
```

```html
<div class="swing"></div>
```

Comment: What is your question?  "Why isn't this working" isn't nearly enough to go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just missed the animation-duration:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes swing {
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 15deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 15deg);
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -10deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -10deg);
  }

  60% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 5deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 5deg);
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -5deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -5deg);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes swing {
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 15deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 15deg);
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -10deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -10deg);
  }

  60% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 5deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 5deg);
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -5deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -5deg);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, 0deg);
  }
}

.swing {
  position:relative;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
}

.swing:hover{
  -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
  transform-origin: top center;
  -webkit-animation-name: swing;
  animation-name: swing;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="swing"></div>
```

[MDN doc for animation-duration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-duration)

Or you could be a little more concise by using the [animation shorthand property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation).

```
.swing:hover{
  -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
  transform-origin: top center;
  animation: swing 1s;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response and for your help. I am really grateful!